# How do I know if need an additionals threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

I have a script in Python which has to be reliable and work 24/7 and preferably never fail. It receives data from a third-party service, then processes it and then saves into a db. It might receive plenty of data at a time or might not.

For the save of reliability, it  saves data first into different files, one new file whenever it receives data.

I wonder, should I create a new thread each time it receives data to speed it up? Or just create one new thread in which I'd say all data into files?
Or new thread(s) for processing data (and) saving it into the db?

I'm thinking of that because data can come when it's busy processing other portion of data which came previously or saving it into a database.

How can I know whether or not I really need that?

Comment: in my opinion, it's not good to write data at any time. It is better to create and write the block (hard disk life, log, CPU). IO may produce problems at any moment to do it.
It determines the size and number of data read per second.

Comment: Depending on how your system is set up, multithreading can potentially cause race conditions on your db/filesystem if you are updating/writing at the same locations. Only use if you conclude that your infrastructure is resilient to said issue. Possibly this skips your definition of 'reliable'.

Comment: @user2464424, there'll be no updates, only inserting.